# concatenated string reason message in require() not displaying

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration, string, require

I'm using **Solidity 0.8.13** and **Truffle 5.5.6**.

I'm just trying to debug a transaction call that fails then reverts when I do truffle migration.
I **temporarily** changed my `onlyOwner` modifier to make the reason message display the values of my `owner` and `msg.sender` into something like below:

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
    //require( msg.sender == owner, "Only Owner can call." ); // this reason message works
    require( msg.sender == owner, string( abi.encodePacked( "Owner mismatch: ", owner, " != ", msg.sender ) ) );
    _;
}
```

However, in the output of `truffle migrate --reset` (where my original issue was happening), it doesn't display the reason message at all and just display:

```
"Foo" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with passing in concatenated string reason message in require()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Strings.sol` library about [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol) and `strings.sol` about [Arachnid](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/blob/master/src/strings.sol) to concatenate strings and build your message.

You can see this example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/blob/master/src/strings.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract Test {
    using Strings for *;
    using strings for *;
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, getMessage(msg.sender, owner));
        _;
    }

    function test() public onlyOwner {
        // TODO: your logic
    }

    function getMessage(address _callingAddress, address _owner) private returns(string memory){
        // Convert Address to String
        string memory _ownerAddress = Strings.toHexString(uint160(uint160(_owner)));
        string memory _calledAddress = Strings.toHexString(uint160(uint160(_callingAddress)));
        // Define two pieces about message
        string memory _firstMessage = "Owner mismatch: ".toSlice().concat(_ownerAddress.toSlice());
        string memory _secondMessage = " != ".toSlice().concat(_calledAddress.toSlice());
        // Concat in one message
        string memory _message = _firstMessage.toSlice().concat(_secondMessage.toSlice());
        return _message; 
    } 
}
```

***UPDATED ANSWER:***

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract Test {
    using Strings for *;
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        string memory _ownerAddress = Strings.toHexString(uint160(uint160(owner)));
        string memory _calledAddress = Strings.toHexString(uint160(uint160(msg.sender)));
        require(msg.sender == owner, string(abi.encodePacked( "Owner mismatch: ", _ownerAddress, " != ", _calledAddress)));
        _;
    }

    function test() public onlyOwner {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing these imported libraries and their usage. But I would like an explanation why `abi.encodePacked()` is not sufficient for this purpose. I used to look for string concatenation and that one was the recommended answer. But for this case is mine it seems not, which really makes me wonder why.

Do we really have to rely with this .toSlice().concat() for string concatenation purposes in Solidity?

Comment: When use abi.encodePacked() method, you must to put into it only  strings. In your smart contract code, you're passing into this method two types like: address (owner and msg.sender) and this is the issue. You must to try to convert this variables to string and then you can add them to abi.encodePacked(). I updated my answer that I hope help you.

Comment: The requirement of strings for `abi.encodePacked` is definitely the best answer.
Also, I've tried your updated example and it works. I also want to know if the double cast of uint160 is necessary there? I tried only once and it works.